# Part of my project started using incorrect connection string - how do I fix that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, xsockets.net

I have *one* solution with *one* project in it. This project is an asp.net mvc web application with xsockets.net websocket server (everything merged inside single project).

Everything was working for a few months, until today. Today I decided to update entity framework and xsockets.net. There were few errors on the way, but I solved almost all of them... almost.

Well, the part of my project that runs websocket server is not using correct connection string. I mean, I can login to my web application, and move around it (so asp.net mvc is using correct connection string), but my websocket server (which is using the same database) cannot gather any data from database, since it's throwing incorrect connection string exception.

And since everything is in the single project, with single web.config file, I don't know what to do next. I don't believe that this is websocket related error, maybe entity framework update has changed something? Anyways, is there any way to explicitly use connection string inside of a class? What else I can do to fix that?

Comment: Have you diffed the old & new connection strings? Off the top of my head I'd guess that the EF upgrade you did altered the connection string into a form that is incompatible with xsockets. If so, you should add a second connection string for xsockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Entity Framework connects to create the entity objects it also establishes the connection string to that database.  This usually isn't a problem since that project is referenced by another program that is overriding the server connection string with their own app config (or web config).

Typically in code when connecting to an instance of Sql Server, you write your code:

```
 using ( MyServer context = new MyServer(myconfig.ConnectionStrings["MyServerName"]))
 {
 }
```

If you exclude providing he connection string when creating the instance of your context, you risk catching the default value created when you updated entity framework.  So this probably answers both your questions: the why is it changed your connection string.  The explicit use is the code example above.

Comment: That would be exactly what I needed. But what exactly is `myconfig`? Is it some kind of a predefined object? Or how can I acces it? Also, I checked it, and as far as I see I cannot use it like that (`MyServer` constructor doesn't allow any parameters)?

Comment: Is is the unique file named app.config in your project.  I wrote that off the top of my head but really it would probably be ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[] to access what you create in your app.config file.